# How can I call .selectedIndex in render()?

Tags: reactjs

In reactjs we delegate changing a node to the render method, how do we call or get properties like `selectedIndex` once we're done modifying it? I'm choosing `selectedIndex` since incidentally it is 0 even if the user has not actually selected anything.

example:

```
render() {
    <CategoryInput
      categories={this.state.categories}
      onValueChange={function(event) {
        // not called when options themselves have changed
      }}
      ref={(input) => {
        if (input) {
          // the is a reference to the instance
        }
      }}
    />

    // now that the categories have been added to the component
    // I'd like to retrieve selectedIndex to use on a sibling's component
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whatever component is doing this render method needs to have `selectedIndex` as a part of its state. So you could have a

```
getInitialState: function() { 
 return this.setState({ selectedIndex: this.state.category[0] })
}
```

to set initial state when it renders and show a selected category
and then the onValueChange function should also setState to whatever category it was changed to

Comment: My concern is that I'm not getting the selectedIndex from the node itself but rather I'm assuming what it will be. Is this guaranteed in the spec? Outside of reactjs I'd just use native DOM procedures.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#why-select-value this goes over the React way of handling selects. It uses the value of what is selected to determine everything. You dont have to worry about selectedIndex just make sure the value matches the value you put in the dropdown

Comment: Thank you. This is sufficient. (thanks for a link to the article I must've read a million times for other reasons -- missed the select section)